# Text mining for financial news, hand-produced dictionary and framework?

Tags: .net, nlp, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

Go straight into the point, for a single piece of financial news, there is no clear border between good or bad news. However, with the shallow understanding, we can know that a news sounds like good news.

Example: MSFT quote rises recently due to.....

Notice that **rises** indicates a rise in quote, so this is good news for those who own MSFT stocks.

Based on this idea, I have a dictionary that each word indicates (or sounds like ) a good news or bad news.

The news is considered as **text**, and the solution is basically based on the dictionary to go through the news information.

**Question**:

1. As I can see this is a very very simple of *text mining*, isn't it?
2. What type of work/task for this in the **Natural Language Processing**?
3. Is there any .NET library or framework that support this (Text mining)?

Comment: 3. Asking about **off-site resouces** is off topic.
Other than that, it sounds like typical sentiment analysis to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward text and sentiment analysis that can be done with many different tools. I currently do something similar with python and nltk.